How to rename sheet in Google Sheets document by using R package googlesheets4?
I would like to rename sheet in Google Sheets document
Here is my code snippet
library(googlesheets4)
library(googledrive)

# Authentication

# 1. Google Sheets
gs4_auth(path = fname_gsheets_key,  scopes = "spreadsheets")
gs4_auth(path = fname_gsheets_key, scopes = "drive")

# 2. List of Google Sheets Documents
gs4_sheets <- gs4_get(gsheets_document)
gs4_sheets
gs4_sheets$sheets

# 3. ID of the sheet to rename
sheet_id_to_rename <- gs4_sheets$sheets %>% filter(name == "name_existing") %>% pull(id)
sheet_id_to_rename

# 4. Attempt to rename >> not works
gs4_find("name_existing") %>% sheet_rename(sheet_id_to_rename, new_name = "name_new")

Will appreciate for workable advice.
Thanks!
